# How to remove linked servers provider?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, oracle-12c, linked-server, oledb

I installed an Oracle OraOLEDB.Oracle provider. Now I want to remove that provider from the list. How can I do that?

Comment: De-install Oracle Client from the server and this would disappear.

Comment: I installed it through command line (from Xcopy zip file). What I have is only oracle folder in my C: drive

Comment: well, I've deleted that provider from physical machine, it still appears in SSMS->Server Objects -> Linked Servers -> Providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the linked server provider, uninstall the OleDb Provider.  For Oracle XCopy use the uninstall.bat in the installation folder, eg

```
PS C:\odacinstall> .\uninstall.bat oledb c:\oracle\odac64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Oracle Universal Installer per [these docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14312/deinstall.htm) from Oracle (assuming you don't have a PL/SQL server installed on the same server as your Microsoft SQL Server, that you want to keep).

Make sure to read through the entire page above, especially the section about manually removing the correlating registry entries which seems to be a common issue with removing providers from Windows, as noted in this [TechNet answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/bb307748-7638-404d-a6a4-982827a051c8/how-do-i-remove-sql-provider-that-was-previously-installed-on-a-remote-sql-server?forum=configmgrgeneral).